# Laravel 5.4 Query within a query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

I am actually doing this sql query applying the join. There is only one table involved which is the 'users'. In this table I have to count how many male and female in every area of the university because it has 6 campuses.I have done this query but I also want to add another query in this group of data where in every area of each gender, the academic ranks will also be counted. I can do this in separate query but I wanted to minimize my queries to at least improve the speed of loading but I do not have the idea what is best to use. Below is the sample query result which i wanted to achieve

1. **Area 101**
      -(*Male: 12*)--
          (Professor: 1
          Associate Professor: 4
          Assistant Professor: 3
          Instructor: 4)
2. **Area 101**
      -(*Female: 15*)--
          (Professor: 0
          Associate Professor: 5
          Assistant Professor: 2
          Instructor: 8)

   1. **Area 102**
      -(*Male: 8*)--
         (Professor: 1
         Associate Professor: 2
         Assistant Professor: 1
         Instructor: 4)
3. **Area 102**
      -(*Female: 11*)--
          (Professor: 1
          Associate Professor: 3
          Assistant Professor: 2
          Instructor: 5)

[Please View Image of Initial Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2t4s.png)

Here is my implemented code but it only queries the first condition.

```
$male_group = User::where('users.gender','=','M')
              ->where('users.r_status', 'A')
              ->join('areas', 'users.areacode', '=', 'areas.area_code')
              ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(users.gender) as count"),'users.areacode','users.gender','areas.area_name')
              ->groupBy('users.gender','areas.area_name',DB::raw("users.areacode"))
              ->paginate();
  $female_group = User::where('users.gender','=','F')
              ->where('users.r_status', 'A')
              ->join('areas', 'users.areacode', '=', 'areas.area_code')
              ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(users.gender) as count"),'users.areacode','users.gender','areas.area_name')
              ->groupBy('users.gender','areas.area_name',DB::raw("users.areacode"))
              ->paginate();
```

Comment: The output/input you are showing us is not in relational table form.  Can you shows sample data in the form of a SQL table?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I forgot to say that I joined table areas and users just to identify the Name of the area because in table users area is in code not by name.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen In table users : (ID,Name,Sex, Areacode, AcademicRankCode)

Comment: Your question is unclear (at least I can't make sense of it).

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I am sorry if it seems unclear but I updated my post and included sample image but witout the academic ranks. I hope you can help me.